# Passing an object to a subview of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

This is probably really simple, but I can't get my head around it.  I have a UIViewController with two UITableView subviews placed on it (using Storyboards).

[image]

These both have custom classes and are used for two separate lists of items.  The custom classes are used because the cells in each UITableView can be dragged and dropped between the tables.  The view controller is segued to and has a Managed Object Context pushed with the segue.

What I can't figure out is how to pass the managed object context (and other objects) to the UITableView subviews.  The objects are defined in the table view class.

I've set IBOutlets to each of the table views, so can reference the UITableViews themselves, but I have no visibility of the custom objects.

How can I pass objects to a custom class subview?

Answer (score 0):

> What I can't figure out is how to pass the managed object context (and
>   other objects) to the UITableView subviews.

First, there shouldn't be a need to pass a managed object context to a subview of a table. UITableView populates itself with cells by talking to its data source -- the table doesn't know anything about the data that it displays. The subviews of a table are its cells, and those come from the data source. Most often, the view controller acts as data source and delegate for the table -- if anything needs to know about a managed object context, it's the data source, and again, that's usually the view controller.

Leaving aside the question of whether you *should* pass a MOC to a table cell or other subview, let's talk about *how* to do it. In order for one object to communicate directly with another, the first object needs a pointer to the second. If you have a pointer to an object, you can send the object any message you like (although it helps a lot if the object implements that method!). So, the first order of business will be to find the view that you want to talk to.

You're talking about implementing drag and drop between your tables, so I'll guess that the subview in question is a table cell and that your drop operation involves changing cell where the touch ends. You can get the table cell where the touch ends by first translating the end point into the table's local coordinates and then using the table's [`-indexPathForRowAtPoint:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForRowAtPoint%3a) method. Once you have the index path for the row, you can get the corresponding cell via [`-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a). With a pointer to the cell, you can send the cell a message passing in whatever parameters you like.

Finally, if you *are* going to take this approach, you probably don't need to pass the managed object context itself. It seems more likely that the data represented by your drag will be a managed object rather than a managed object *context*, so it's the managed object that you probably want to pass around. A context is a container for a number of managed objects, and every managed object has a reference to the context in which it exists, so there's no need to pass the context separately.

Comment: ok, I see what you're saying and thanks for the detailed answer, but I'm not sure how this works when both the UITableViews have a (different) custom class.  The code for handling the drag and drop is contained within these classes, and so I need to have access to the core data objects within each.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a custom cell and pass it the managed object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
}
@property (weak) NSManagedObject *managedObject
@end
```

then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell =
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // get your managed object
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.managedObject = managedObject;
}
```

and so on.

Also, you might find it really convenient to use a Core Data framework such as [Sensible TableView](http://sensiblecocoa.com). The framework will automatically handle filling the data in for all the cells fields, and will also auto generate all detail views. Saves me tons of time when working with Core Data.